# How to create ScrollBar for SWF file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, browser, scroll

I am trying to build a AS3 only project and I ran into a problem that when I turn some MC's visible on...they are out of my browser window and there is no scrollBar for browser to scroll down.....Are there anyways around this?? Thanks for the reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the HTML container is not big enough. The flash content will crop to fit the DIV container.

If you are using SWFObject to embed your SWF in your HTML page (I seriously recommend you should be) then I suggest using [SWFFit](http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/). You can use it to change your SWFs container dynamically at runtime, by calling a method with your SWFs new height and/or width. This means that the default browser srollbars will show if needed.